# Can't make a connection to a db thru php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is my first time mixing PHP and SQL, and my problem is that I cannot connect to my database with PHP.
I am using `mysql_connect` (and I've also found `mysqli_connect`, I can't see the difference).

This is my code:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password","db_name");
```

I have put it between `< ?php` and a `?>` in my index.php file.
And all it has showed me so far is this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_connect' (T_STRING) in /home/username/domains/website.com/public_html/index.php on line 63
```

I can't see the problem since I've been doing everything according to W3C's tutorial.

Comment: Please post all of your code.There is something else surrounding it causing this problem.

Comment: The problem may be caused by code *before* the code you gave us here. Are you sure you're not missing any semicolons or similar?

Comment: You mention "the w3C's tutorial". Hopefully you are not referring to w3schools.com, which is _not_ of the W3C, and generally not well regarded.

Comment: Since you are new, if you are using a tutorial recommending `mysql_connect()`, you should find a more up to date tutorial right away. The `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5, and will be removed entirely in the future. Instead, consider learning PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: sorry guys... my mistake was that I had put a space between the `<?` and the php at the start of the code..Sorry for bothering you..<br/><br/>P.S.<br/>I'm very glad to see how fast people respond here..be sure that I will keep asking questions since I'm new to the web environment.

Comment: Do not use HTML in the comments. Also never use 2*<br/> after one another

Answer (score 1):

You must assign the return of mysql_connect !

$link = mysql_connect(...);

### If you need to do database connection it's time to take a look at PHP documentation :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Warning

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

```
mysqli_connect()
PDO::__construct()
```

---

If you're starting a project I think you haven't set all your queries statements and it'd be a great idea to change to mysqli or pdo now. Migrating parts of code is always a pain since you need to do all application tests for non regression.